# how to analyze /proc/pid/smaps

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory

hi i am in need of your help guys again, i need to analyze smaps. of c files.
check this out:

> The other lines provide a number of extra details including:
>
> The mapping size (Size)
>
> The proportional share of this mapping that belongs to the process
> (Pss)
>
> The amount of the mapping that currently sits in RAM (Rss)
>
> The amount of memory currently marked as referenced or accessed
> (Referenced)
>
> How many dirty and clean private pages are in the mapping
> (Private_Dirty and Private_Clean respectively). Note: Even if a page
> is part of the MAP_SHARED mapping, if it has only one pte mapped, is
> counted as private (not as shared).
>
> The amount of memory that does not belong to any file (Anonymous)
>
> The amount of would-be-anonymous memory that is used but stored on
> swap (Swap)

and this is a typical smaps file:

> Size:                  4 kB
>
> KernelPageSize:        4 kB
>
> MMUPageSize:           4 kB
>
> Rss:                   4 kB
>
> Pss:                   4 kB
>
> Shared_Clean:          0 kB
>
> Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
>
> Private_Clean:         4 kB
>
> Private_Dirty:         0 kB
>
> Referenced:            4 kB
>
> Anonymous:             0 kB
>
> LazyFree:              0 kB
>
> AnonHugePages:         0 kB
>
> ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
>
> FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
>
> Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
>
> Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
>
> Swap:                  0 kB
>
> SwapPss:               0 kB
>
> Locked:                0 kB
>
> THPeligible:      0
>
> VmFlags: rd mr mw me dw sd

so i just want to know how much memory the process takes, as i understand i need to sum the pss, the actual physical memory allocated, with the rss, the virtual memory utilized. am i wrong?

Comment: what does the linux documentation say?

Comment: What do you mean by "how much memory the process takes". It may seem obvious to you, but to me that could mean many different things. Memory that cannot be used by other processes? Memory allocation that are actually used? etc.

Comment: @Cheatah im sorry, yes i meant memory allocation that is actually been used, should i add pss , rss and referenced?  because tha'ts the logical thing to do as far as i understand.